# which order do we perform the exponents $x^{2*1/2}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

For $x^{2*1/2}$, do we do $\sqrt x^{2} $ or $ \sqrt{x^{2}}$ ? the reason is because the second one is defined for the entire real line and is equal to |x| whereas the first one is only defined for positive numbers. But at the same time, the rules of exponents say the order is commutative so we should not have two different answers. How do we reconcile this?

Answer (score 2):

Neither, to calculate $x^{2*1/2}$ you do the multiplication first to get $x^1=x$.

And

$\sqrt{x}^2=(x^{1/2})^2$

$\sqrt{x^2}=(x^2)^{1/2}$

but in general, $x^{ab}\ne (x^a)^b$

Comment: but in general, $x^{ab}\ne (x^a)^b$ It doesn't make much more sense..

Comment: @lonestudent Under certain conditions, $x^{ab}=(x^a)^b$. For example, if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $x$ is any real number, or if  $a$ , $b$ real numbers and $x>0$. But, in general,  the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: Except $x<0$ with $a,b \not \in\mathbb Z$ and $x^{ab} \in\mathbb R$, then the equality holds.

Comment: So, as I said, not valid in general.

Comment: What I meant was to emphasize that when you just say "in general not true" it is useless for the OP and makes the rule something trivial.

Comment: By the way I could not edit my comment... $x^{ab}\in\mathbb R$ and $(x^a) \in\mathbb R$.

Comment: It's useful for the OP. His question arise precisely because he was thinking that $x^{2*1/2}$ had to be one of $(x^{1/2}) ^2$ or $(x^2)^{1/2}$ because the rules of exponents.

Comment: Then if I were OP, I would ask.  If it is not generally true, on what basis did you apply this rule?  It would then be necessary to make a statement. I'm ending the discussion.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

First see the comments of jjagmath and myself that follow this answer.

---

The rule of exponents does say that order is commutative, so you never have two different answers.  However, the domain of the two functions is different.  Therefore, an element $x$ can be in the domain of one of the functions, and out of the domain of the other function.

Personally, I think the expression $x^{2 \times (1/2)}$ is ambiguous and might reasonably be construed to represent either

- $(x^2)^{(1/2)}$ or
- $x^{2 \times (1/2)} = x^{1}$, since $[2 \times (1/2)] = 1.$

It depends on the order of evaluation.

Personally, I would not evaluate it as $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2$, because I regard that as being represented by
$x^{(1/2) \times 2}$, which I regard as different from
$x^{2 \times (1/2)}$.

---

Note that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$
and that (in Real Analysis) 
$\left(\sqrt{x}~\right)^2$ is undefined when $x < 0.$  
When $x \geq 0$, then $\left(\sqrt{x}~\right)^2$ evaluates the same way that $\sqrt{x^2}$ does.

Comment: $x^{2\times 1/2}$ is not ambiguous.

Comment: @jjagmath I'm not disagreeing with you, but merely saying that I am unaware of the convention that you multiply the exponents first.  Therefore, since I am unaware of the convention, it is unclear how universal the convention is.

Comment: $x^y$ is a notation for a binary operation. The first operand is $x$, the second operator is $y$, independently of the form of $x$ or $y$. Interpreting $x^{y z}$ otherwise would mean that this is a ternary operation. I've never seen such an interpretation.

Comment: @jjagmath "...would mean that this is a ternary operation. I've never seen such an interpretation." To tell you the truth, neither have I.  In fact, I *suspect* that you are correct.  But I don't **know** that you are correct.